# Difference in sorting behaviour based on LANG setting

Tags: linux, sort, locale

I ran following two commands with different LANG settings :

```
~$ LANG= sort <<< $'x\n_y\nz'
_y
x
z
~$ LANG=en_US.UTF-8 sort <<< $'x\n_y\nz'
x
_y
z
```

Can someone explain why there is this difference of output ?

Comment: Because the Locale for each language defines the collating sequence of punctuation, multibyte chars, dictionary ordering, upper/lower case, and numbers with separator symbols.

Comment: When `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`, why `_y` is sorted between x and z, how is `_` interpreted ?

Comment: See `http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr10/` --specially section 1.8. If en_US.UTF-8 is defined as a Dictionary collating sequence in the relevant standard, anything not alphanumeric is omitted from consideration in the sort keys. If you want an ASCII sort, `export LC_ALL="C"` before you sort. `join, diff and uniq` are also affected by this issue.

Comment: That explains it, thanks!